# How much Ruby do I have to cover in order to start learning Sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra

My overall experience with programming is DOM manipulation with jQuery, little Ajax with it too, also some raw javascript (codecademy course). Now I decided to learn Sinatra (read that RoR is too complex for non-savvy progammers) but I am aware that I need to understand some Ruby to start learning this framework, thus the question is how much Ruby do I need to cover?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is a set amount. Like anything else, the more the better.

If you were to read Chris Pine's [Learn to Program](http://pine.fm/LearnToProgram/) it would give you all the basic ruby functionality you would need to get by. It is probably the best intro to ruby book out there that will cover things like iteration, classes, methods, blocks and procs.

Comment: Also, if you are learning Sinatra, I highly recommend: http://sinatra-book.gittr.com/

Comment: I have no access to Chris Pine's book.

Comment: A version of it is available online via that link I posted.

Answer (score 0):

[_why's poignant guide to ruby](http://mislav.uniqpath.com/poignant-guide/) is a great start for learning ruby.  If you want to get a handle on the language first, I'd recommend starting there.  If you'd rather learn as you go, the [sinatra book](http://sinatra-book.gittr.com/) is free and should provide a great start.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll have a much easier time in the long run if you take a few weeks and get very comfortable in Ruby now. Work through the Ruby Monk course and don't move on from a concept until you have it. You only have to learn these concepts once and then learning additional languages is a breeze!